# We’ve detected that your app is using an old version of the Google Play Billing. By Nov 2021 all the app updates must use version 3 or newer

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-billing

We’ve detected that your app is using an old version of the **Google Play Billing**. By Nov 2021 all the app updates must use version 3 or newer.

How to update this?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have updated your Google play billing dependency to `com.android.billingclient:billing:3.0.0` or above and implemented any changes that dove happened between the library versions. For more information check out the documentation: https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/integrate

Comment: Did you know shall I need InAppBillingService.java file for the latest billing versions? Because according to the migration doc, they have removed the vending. After the removal the package is available.